# SQL Server 2014: missing replication option

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151192.aspx) details exact steps to set up basic database replication with SQL Server 2014.

It starts with this:

> 2. Right-click the Replication folder, and then click Configure Distribution.

On right clicking my Replication folder (I do believe I installed replication), I only get the following options:

```
Launch Replication Monitor
Generate Scripts....
Update Replication Passwords...
```

I can't find any other place in SQL Server Mgmt Studio to get to this section. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely using the Express Edition.  Note that Express Edition can only act as a Subscriber.  Try using Standard Edition or above to Configure Distribution and Publishing.